# Required parameter ‘theme_dir’ was not passed

Tags: magento2, product-images

[image]

[image]

The theme exist in backoffice and in my code but when trying to add product i get this error : Required parameter ‘theme_dir’ was not passed
please help and thanks in advance

Comment: Did you deleted any theme?

Comment: no that the problem no theme deleted

Comment: but  it show me this error

Comment: Delete all the content of folder var/view_preprocessed & pub/static/frontend

Comment: in  the pictures you can see that Mytheme is under design and also it appears in the backoffice and the DB

Comment: Can you post your registration.php and theme.xml?

Comment: <?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::THEME, 'frontend/Magenticians/Mytheme', __DIR__
);

Comment: <theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
    <title>Mytheme</title>
    <parent>Magento/blank</parent>
    <media>
        <preview_image>media/preview.png</preview_image>
    </media>
</theme>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83337/discussion-between-sukumar-gorai-and-developper-magento).

Comment: I renamed the theme and do it the changes on theme.xml and registration and run the commanbde static: deploy and upgrade indexer:reindex and cache:clean and cache:flush but no result

Answer (score 0):

You need do indexing for design flat table.

Do indexing using the command line

> php bin/magento indexer:reindex design_config_grid

Also check database table `theme`

Ensure  the theme folders **should available at system respect to that table list**

Comment: i checked theme folders and also run the commande but no result